# Set Contact Number in Contact Uri

Tags: android, android-contacts

In my application i want to add the contact number . So here i called the Below code . It call the Add contact screen but i want to set the contact number using code . can any one help me to solve my problem ?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT,People.CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

It is called Add Contact Screen .

[image: In the Phone edit text i want to add the phone number using code]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Solution.

```
Intent addContactIntent = new Intent(Contacts.Intents.Insert.ACTION, Contacts.People.CONTENT_URI);
addContactIntent.putExtra(Contacts.Intents.Insert.PHONE,"Phone Number"); 
startActivity(addContactIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know INSERT creates an empty contact. Maybe you can create an entry and then call the action.EDIT pointing to he new contact